# startActivityForResult and proceed when activity is complete

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm working on processing an image taken with android intent. I noticed that startActivityForResult launches the activity and proceeds to the next lines of code (which is where my processing code is). Is there a way to proceed only when the activity is complete? I'm aware of putting code in onActivityResult, but when I try that my processing doesn't work and I get the message "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." Here is a sample of my code.

```
package e.app.test;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.RotatedRect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.utils.Converters;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button takePictureButton;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Uri file;
    private Bitmap largeBitmap,scaled,processedBMP;
    volatile boolean IntentComplete = false;
    int h,w;


    //image holder
    Mat bwIMG, dsIMG, usIMG, cIMG, hovIMG;
    MatOfPoint2f approxCurve;

    Mat dst;
    Mat gray;
    Mat processedMat;

    // Vertices of
    short numberOfStrips = 0;
    Point[] extendedVertices = new Point[4];
    Point[] vertices = new Point[4];
    Point pt = new Point(0,0); //Temporary point variable
    int threshold;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        takePictureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_image);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            takePictureButton.setEnabled(false);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
        }
        takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                takePicture(view);
                // WHERE I WANT TO DO MY HEAVY PROCESSING
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                takePictureButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void takePicture(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        file = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "e.stcm.c_stick_interface.fileprovider", getOutputMediaFile());
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("CameraDemo", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //processedFile = file;
                try
                {
                    //WHERE I TRIED TO DO MY HEAVY PROCESSING
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //handle exception
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are doing in next lines of code ?

Comment: It's a bunch of processing. I'm resizing the image, then identifying and cropping rectangle contours in the image and then sending it to a remote server.

Comment: AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      //TODO your background code
//Write your code here ....which you want to execute after capture
   }
});

Comment: Excuse me for being a noob, I tried looking at the link from @Marcelo and your code snippet but I can't seem to figure out where to put it in the code I just uploaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() { 
     @Override public void run() { 
            //Write your code here which you want to execute after capture 
     }});} } }
```

//Put your code inside run method.The code which you want to run after capturing snip.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an asynctask, this will alleviate the work being done on the main thread and then you can use the result of this to proceed as wanted . https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask for more information.

Answer (score 1):

you need to complete the rest of the actions you need using `void OnActyivityResult()` on your activity

like this:

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 //do stuffs
                }
           }

        }
```

Comment: Yes, I've mentioned that I tried that, my processing doesn't work and I get the message "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."